# Oracle CONNECT BY and MAX

Tags: oracle

I am having difficulty integrating a MAX into a query and would greatly appreciate any help.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this: list a supervisor's supervisor's supervised employees along with their latest "day out" punch time.

The part I can't get right is the MAX(day out) part.

**Here's the part I got so far that works fine**:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.NUMBER, 
       EMPLOYEE.NAME, 
       S.NAME AS SUPERVISOR,
       EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ON EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE S ON S.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
WHERE LEVEL =2 
START WITH EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.USERID = (ID OF SUPERVISOR HERE)
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPLOYEE.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
```

This part works and gives me the basic input that I need. However, I also need to list, for each employee, his/her lastest "day out" date.

**Here's what I tried tried that didn't work**:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.NUMBER, 
       EMPLOYEE.NAME, 
       S.NAME AS SUPERVISOR,
       EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE,
       MAX(EMPLOYEE_TIME.DATE_OUT)
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ON EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE S ON S.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_TIME ON EMPLOYEE_TIME.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
WHERE LEVEL =2 
START WITH EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.USERID = (ID OF SUPERVISOR HERE)
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPLOYEE.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
GROUP BY
       EMPLOYEE.NUMBER, 
       EMPLOYEE.NAME, 
       S.NAME,
       EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
HAVING MAX(EMPLOYEE_TIME.DATE_OUT) >= SYSDATE-60
```

It doesn't throw any error, it just keeps on processing forever. I'm guessing something must be looping but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How big is employee_time table? and the index on it is?

Comment: Your `connect by` is happening after all the joins, so your hierarchy is going to be much larger than you expect. You need to identify the ID(s) you're interested in as a subquery of some kind, and join the *results* of that subquery to the `employee_time` table. You don't really need the `connect by` here though, I think.

Comment: @AlexPoole did. i answer the same just now?

Comment: @Alex Poole of course those aren't the real field names. As for self-joins along with connect by, that self-join is used for fishing out the supervisor name, since supervisors are in the same table as the other employees. Connect by is for the hierarchy between supervisors and employees. As for a "query that runs", the first query I posted ran fine, my problem was figuring out the right syntax for the 2nd query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight change to your query in joining the time table, it need not be joined while `CONNECT BY`, instead separate it.

```
SELECT NUMBER, 
       EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
       SUPERVISOR,
       HIRE_DATE,
       MAX(TIME.DATE_OUT)
FROM
(SELECT NUMBER, 
       EMPLOYEE.NAME AS EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       S.NAME AS SUPERVISOR,
       EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ON EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE S ON S.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER
WHERE LEVEL =2 
START WITH EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.USERID = (ID OF SUPERVISOR HERE)
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPLOYEE.NUMBER = EMPLOYEE.SUPERVISOR_NUMBER) EMP_SUP
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_TIME TIME
ON( EMP_SUP.NUMBER = TIME.NUMBER)
GROUP BY
       NUMBER, 
       EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
       SUPERVISOR,
       HIRE_DATE
HAVING MAX(DATE_OUT) >= SYSDATE-60
```

Comment: AMAZING, thank you so much. And thank you for understanding the fact that I had to use fake field names here :)